# Ruby code memory leak in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.1

Below code is having memory leak. It's running under ruby 2.1.1. I am not able to find the actual leak.

```
q = Queue.new("test")
while true do
  m = q.dequeue
  body = JSON.parse(m.body)
  user_id = body["Records"][0]
  user = V2::User.find(user_id)
  post = V2::Post.find(post_id)  
end
```

After few hours of run I added GC.start but its not solving the problem

```
q = Queue.new("test")
while true do
  m = q.dequeue
  body = JSON.parse(m.body)
  user_id = body["Records"][0]
  user = V2::User.find(user_id)
  post = V2::Post.find(post_id) 
  GC.start 
end
```

I don't know how to find the actual memory leak.

Comment: How is `Queue` defined? What does `Queue#dequeue` look like (I noticed `dequeue` is not defined for the `Queue` that comes with Ruby)? Who enqueues objects into the queue? How many objects are in the queue on average?

Comment: Did your question get answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the lines from the bottom up, and seeing if the memory leak persists. It's possible that the Memory leak is coming from the find method, or possibly the JSON.parse (extremely unlikely), or the custom Queue data structure. If the memory leak is still there after removing all of the lines, it is likely coming from the worker itself and/or the program running the workers.

```
q = Queue.new("test")
while true do
  m = q.dequeue # Finally remove this and stub the while true with a sleep or something
  body = JSON.parse(m.body) # Then remove these two lines
  user_id = body["Records"][0]
  user = V2::User.find(user_id) # Remove the bottom two lines first
  post = V2::Post.find(post_id)
end
```

Comment: At a first glance I was thinking the same. That loop would lead to a high CPU usage for sure, but why should it lead to a high memory usage?

Comment: @Dbz Actually its a worker. It will run for every sec. It will Liston the queue. if any message is pushed to queue it will take the message from queue and do the job.

Comment: Yup. You guys are definitely correct. I've updated my answer with debugging tips. Make sure to post the results after trying this.

Comment: @SaravanaKumAr How on the Earth the answer consisting of “probably” and “likely” got approved as correct? Did you check this assumption? You claimed it took hours for the leak to notice? Please avoid marking answers that **were not proven to work for you**.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think you linked to an excellent and informative stack overflow answer. His question stated he did not know **how** to find the memory leak. If my answer including 'probably' and 'likely' was able to help him find the memory leak, **and it worked for him**, then it doesn't seem unreasonable to up vote and/or mark it accepted. That being said, your answer on **why** and what he can do is equally important.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is with introduced local variables (sic!). Get rid of `user_id` and `post_id` and it’ll likely stop leaking:

```
# user_id = body["Records"][0]
# user = V2::User.find(user_id)
user = V2::User.find(body["Records"][0]) # sic!
```

The reason is how Ruby [stores objects in RValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385767/finding-the-cause-of-a-memory-leak-in-ruby/20608455#20608455).

Comment: After each GC.start the local variables memory will be freed rite?

Comment: For example am running a loop 1000 times. Inside that loop each time am just assigning user_id = some_value. Also each loop am running GC.start too. In that case when the memory will be freed?. What's your view on this.
while i < 1000
  i++
  user_id = i
  GC.start
end

Comment: I have linked a detailed description and asked you to read it twice. `GC` **does not release heaps**. Let me repeat it again: `GC` **does not release heaps**. It does not matter how many times you have it run, `GC` **does not release heaps**. So, on each subsequent iteration of the loop,  each `user_id`, that obviously fits 40 bytes, will allocate a new heap that **will not be released back to OS**.

Comment: I understood your answer. What am asking is when that heap will released back to OS?

Comment: Never. **Please read the answer I linked**, it contains a detailed explanation.

Comment: Never. Your answer doesn't clarify when the heap memory released back to OS?

Comment: Are you bullying at me? The heap memory is **never released back to OS**.

Comment: Heap memory reserved by Ruby is release when the process terminates.  But you are right @SaravanaKumAr - the memory generally should go back into the available pool for Ruby if it is garbage collected.  Defining when that happens is beyond my expertise, but involves RValues (as mentioned in this answer), and references and scopes, and GC settings, etc.